Git workflow to overwrite remote commits with local ones
Often I run into this scenario:

only one branch, say master
initially, both local and remote repositories are in sync (both have the same commits history)
due to a mistake, a coworker push on the remote server some commits, i.e. C1 and C2
in my local repository I also have my commits L1 and L2 (not pushed yet) that conflict with C1 and C2

The goal is to "replace" / "overwrite" / "ignore" (I really don't know the correct git term here) the remote commits with mine. In other words, the actual content of the repository should be just L1 and L2 as the other commits weren't there.
I cannot ask to revert the last commits pushed by the coworker.
Usually I do a standard merge, manually accepting the local changes, but it can be tedious if he changed lot of stuff.
Is there a quicker way to achieve the same result?

Consider instead protecting the master branch (nobody can directly commit to it) and requiring everyone to work in branches and only merge after checks have passed and reviewers approve. Sites such as Github and Gitlab provide these protections.

@Schwern, it's a different matter. He can commit to master, but sometimes he pushes wrong content, and I have to fix the conflicts in the way described above

And you have to clean up their mess? If he keeps making mistakes like this, maybe he shouldn't. You said "conflict", is there an actual merge conflict? Have L1 and L2 been pushed? A git log --graph --decorate --all --oneline showing the relevant commits and branches would help.

@Schwern I appreciate, but that's not the question. Yes, there are merge conflicts (changes on the same files) and L1 and L2 have not been pushed yet.

What you're asking for is potentially destructive. Providing us with a sanitized git log --graph --decorate --all --oneline showing the relevant branches (origin/master and master) and commits would help ensure we fully understand your situation.

If I understand correctly, you have this:
remote
A - B - C1 - C2 [master]

local
A - B - L1 - L2 [master]

And you want the remote to match your local like this.
remote
A - B - L1 - L2 [master]

local
A - B - L1 - L2 [master]

C1 and C2 will be completely gone.
You can do a git push --force to make the remote master match your local.
However, after that force push everyone else who has pulled C1 and C2, and your co-worker, will be in this situation.
remote
A - B - L1 - L2 [master]

local
A - B - C1 - C2 - L3 - L4 [master]

L3 - L4 are their own local commits on top of C1 - C2. If they try to push it will fail. git status will tell them they have "diverged" with their remote, their local changes cannot be put on top of remote's master, and git push will not merge them.
To fix this, people should git pull --rebase. This will replay their local commits on top of the remote's master. This may cause conflict if they made their work on top of C1 - C2.
$ git pull --rebase

remote
A - B - L1 - L2 [master]

local
A - B - L1 - L2 - L3 - L4 [master]

git pull --rebase should be your default. I recommend setting pull.rebase to true or merges so git pull will rebase by default. This avoids unnecessary "update" merges, and smooths over these diverge issues.

UPDATE

By the way, I want the actual content is the same of the local changes, it does not matter about the git history.

Then git revert the changes, it's much safer.
First, put your changes into a branch. It should be normal procedure to work in a branch, not master, for just this reason. Branches protect you from getting in the way of others, and vice-versa.
$ git switch master
$ git branch mywork

      C1 - C2 [origin/master]
     /
A - B - L1 - L2 [master]
                [mywork]

Then move your master to match origin/master.
$ git reset --hard origin/master

              [master]
      C1 - C2 [origin/master]
     /
A - B - L1 - L2 [mywork]

Now git revert the mistaken commits. Do them in reverse order to avoid conflicts.
$ git revert C2 C1

              2C - 1C [master]
             /
      C1 - C2 [origin/master]
     /
A - B - L1 - L2 [mywork]

And push.
$ git push

      C1 - C2 - 2C - 1C [master][origin/master]
     /
A - B - L1 - L2 [mywork]

Pushing isn't strictly necessary, but this is a mistake you'll want to fix as soon as possible before other people start putting their work on top of it. It's also polite to inform the team you've reverted those commits and they should pull as soon as possible before they base their own on the reverted work.
Now you can merge your work into master, delete your branch, and push.
$ git switch master
$ git merge mywork
$ git branch -d mywork
$ git push

      C1 - C2 - 2C - 1C - M [master][origin/master]
     /                   /
A - B - L1 ----------- L2


This is a disruptive situation. Most projects avoid this problem by not allowing anyone to push to the master branch, even the boss... especially the boss. All work must be done in branches. Branches must pass automated checks and peer review before they can be merged. This is the feature branch workflow. It ensures your master branch remains a high quality basis for more work, and avoids mistakes like this.
Most Git services provide this and more. For example, Github's About protected branches. If you're using a home-rolled system, you can write a server-side update hook to reject pushes to master.

Correct, thanks. By the way, I want the actual content is the same of the local changes, it does not matter about the git history

@Mark In that case, git revert them. It's much safer and you don't have to coordinate with everyone.

@Mark I've updated the answer to show how to revert. I cannot emphasize enough that working in branches avoids these and many other problems. Even if the rest of the team isn't using branches, you can.
